# How I implement Multithread pool for a repetitive process

Tags: c#, multithreading

I need to do something like this Test() is just calculations, I only want to put all cpu core at work to find the solution faster.

```
for (int i= 0; i<1000000; i++) 
{
    result[i] = Test(i);
    if (result[i] == 0) 
    {
        break;
    }
}
```

I have work with BackgroundWorker before. And could create an array of N bgWorker and handle a queue by myself but looks too much trouble.

So I found Task.Factory, seem similar to what I want, but still don't know how handle each separate task to wait for the result and stop everything when found the asnwer.

```
Task<string> task = Task.Factory.StartNew<string>
                    (() => DownloadString("http://www.google.com/"));
string result = task.Result;
```

Or maybe is there other solution for my problem.

Comment: So, you want to have multiple threads do the same calculation, and stop when one of them gets the answer you're expecting?

Comment: You want [`Parallel.For`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460713(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @zimdanen well I want each thread handle the same function `Test(i)` and when they finish pick the next available `i` until one found the answer.

Comment: Why not using a `ThreadPool` https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686760(v=vs.85).aspx and https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadpool(v=vs.110).aspx ?

Comment: He's not doing any CPU bound work. It's all IO. No need for `Parallel.For` at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Parallel.For(0, 1000000, (i, loopState) =>
{
    result[i] = Test(i);
    if (result[i] == 0) 
    {
        loopState.Stop();
        return;
    }
});
```

> [How to: Write a Simple Parallel.For Loop](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460713%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
>
> [How to: Stop or Break from a Parallel.For Loop](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460721%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You actually don't need to put multiple cores to use since you're doing IO bound work.

You could take advantage of naturally async APIs for HTTP requests, such as those exposed by `HttpClient`. Then, you could asynchronously check each task as ot completes if it contains the correct result:

```
public async Task FindResultAsync(string[] urlList)
{
     var downloadTasks = urlList.Select(url => DownloadStringAsync(url)).ToList();

     while (downloadTasks.Count > 0)
     {
          await finishedTask = Task.WhenAny(downloadTasks)

          if (finishedTask.Result == someValue)
          {
               return finishedTask.Result;
          }
          downloadTasks.Remove(finishedTask);
      }
}
```